# Generating Function for $(4,9,16,25,36,.....)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I have a sequence $(4,9,16,25,36,...)$ it is being generated by $a_n=(n+1)^2)$

I have found the generating function for $n^2$ here: 
[Proving the generating function of $n^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2432711/proving-the-generating-function-of-$n2$).

I know I can shift a sequence:
$(1,4,9,16,25,....)$ to the right $(0,1,4,9,25,...)$ via $x^1*A(x)$ with $ A(x)$ a generating function. Does this also work with a left shift? Is there a definition? $n$ was a natural numbers. Maybe something else?

Comment: Your guess is reasonable, but without further context, you cannot PROVE that $a_n=(n+1)^2$ is the generating term. But I think we can assume that here, right ?

Comment: Yes, the same trick works in reverse, after you subtract the constant term to make the first coefficient be 0. In this case, if the generating function $f$ is for the sequence (1,4,9,...), then $f(x)=1+4x+9x^2+...$, so $\frac{f(x)-1}{x} = 4+9x+16x^2+...$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(t)=t^2+t^3+t^4+\dots=\dfrac{t^2}{1-t}$, for $|t|<1$.

Then $f'(t)=2t+3t^2+4t^3+\dots=\dfrac{2t-t^2}{(1-t)^2}$

And

$$\dfrac{\mathrm d\left(tf'(t)\right)}{\mathrm dt}=4t+9t^2+16t^3\dots=\frac{t^3-3t^2+4t}{(1-t)^3}$$

Finally

$$4+9t+16t^2+\dots=\frac{t^2-3t+4}{(1-t)^3}$$

Comment: Looks awesome,....but one small question, how "insert here a very bad word of your choise ;-)" shoudl one see that? Any hints? Or a book? Excersises with Solution? I understand that generating functions are very usefull but how to study it. My prof. say :2 seep one night over,...it will get better " :)

Comment: @thetha It's a very basic trick to make the right coefficient appear when you differentiate: multiply by the correct power $t^k$ so that the coefficient of $t^n$ in the series will be multiplied by $n+k$. That's needed because if you differentiate the series $1+t+t^2+t^3+\dots$ several times without adjustment, you will get first $n$, then $n(n-1)$, then $n(n-1)(n-2)$. To get $n$, $n^2$, $n^3$, multiply by $t$ before differentiating again.

Comment: @thetha I suggest *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/gkp.html)* and *[Generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html)* (there is a free version of the latter online)

Comment: Thank you, i have them both, but they are very "dense" ,Concrete Mathematics  is an awesome book, but it a very hard one.

Answer (score 1):

We consider a power series $A(x)$ with constant term $a_0=0$.
\begin{align*}
A(x)=\sum_{j=j_0}^\infty a_jx^j
\end{align*}
A power series $B(x)=\sum_{j=j_0}^\infty a_{j+1}x^j$ can be derived via
\begin{align*}
A(x)&=\sum_{j=j_0}^\infty a_j x^j=\sum_{j=j_0-1}^\infty a_{j+1} x^{j+1}\\
&=x\sum_{j=j_0}^\infty a_{j+1}x^j+a_{j_0}x^{j_0}\\
&=xB(x)+a_{j_0}x^{j_0}
\end{align*}

> We conclude the left-shifted power series $B(x)$ has the representation
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{B(x)=\frac{1}{x}A(x)-a_{j_0}x^{j_0-1}}
> \end{align*}
>
> In the current situation we have
>   \begin{align*}
> A(x)&=\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}\\
> &=x+4x^2+9x^3+16x^4+\cdots\\\\
> \color{blue}{B(x)}&=\frac{1}{x}A(x)-1\\
> &=\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^3}-1\\
> &=\frac{x(x^2-3x+4)}{(1-x)^3}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=4x+9x^2+16x^3+\cdots}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to think about it is to consider the forward differences of the sequence, $1,4,9,16,25,\ldots$ which is $3,5,7,9,\ldots$, and then forward differencing again we get constants.  We translate this into generating function language:

Knowing that $$f(x) = 4 + 9x + 16x^2 + 25x^3 + \cdots$$

We calculate that $$\tag{1} f(x) - xf(x) - 4 = 5x + 7x^2 + 9x^3 + \cdots \equiv g(x)$$

and then $$\tag{2} g(x) - xg(x) - 5x = 2x^2 + 2x^3 + 2x^4 + \cdots = \frac{2x^2}{1-x}$$

From $(2)$ we solve for $g(x)$ as $$g(x) = \frac{-3x^2 + 5x}{(1-x)^2}$$

and then substitute back into $(1)$ to find

$f(x) = \frac{g(x) + 4}{1-x} = \frac{x^2 - 3x + 4}{(1-x)^3}$

This gives a good brute force approach for computing the generating function of any sequence whose terms are given by evaluating a polynomial at evenly spaced points.